# How to make Grails development less dependant from Amazon EC2

Tags: grails, amazon-ec2, grails-2.0

Today I was converting a web application that use Grails 1.3 to 2.0 when I notice longer and longer response times trying to compile and run. An hour later, after deleting the local ivy cache and some files related with the IDE, came to the conclusion that the problem was an [Amazon EC2 outage affecting several sites](http://www.theverge.com/2012/10/22/3539756/reddit-flipboard-minecraft-amazon-outage) including Grails' repositories. Every time I write a simple command as `grails compile` or even `grails help`, the framework try to connect to EC2. We have a Nexus repository where we store our projects and dependencies. There is something we can configure in order to avoid this behavior and use the local Nexus instead? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glen Smith wrote a great article about this: http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2012/06/04/seriously-offline-grails-going-totally-sans-internet-with-nexus.html